# Почему не работает парсинг сайта?

Tags: python, scrapy, веб-скрейпинг

Возможно я сделал что-то не то. Сначала я хочу авторизоваться на сайте, что у меня получилось, далее я собирался парсить нужные мне данные, но у меня это не удалось, я полез по запросам и понял, что мне в запросе прилетает json, думаю спарсить ссылку на этот json(третья ссылка в коде), но мне это тоже не удается, позже выясняется, что ссылка меняется с каждой авторизацией, полазив в html разметке, мне удается найти такой же ключ в html, я его забираю вставляю в ссылку, но чуда не происходит, возникает ошибка(скриншот, верхняя часть это как должно быть, а нижняя это то, что мне прилетает в терминале).Как мне спарсить меняющуюся ссылку на json?Логин и пароль явно указал неправильно. Если что-то непонятно, могу дать больше информации, просто ну ооочень нужно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
session = requests.Session()
link = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/login/index.php'
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': user.random
}

response = session.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
login_token = soup.find('input', {'name': "logintoken"})['value']

data = {
    "logintoken": login_token,
    "username": '8888888888',
    "password": '88888888'
}
response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)

profile_info = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru'
profile_response = session.get(profile_info)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(profile_response.text, 'lxml')
soup2 = soup1.select_one('.logininfo')  # Место, где храниться ключ
soup3 = str(soup2).split('=')[-1].split('"')[0]
profile_info1 = f'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/lib/ajax/service.php?sesskey={soup3}&info=core_calendar_get_action_events_by_timesort'
profile_response1 = session.get(profile_info1)
soup11 = BeautifulSoup(profile_response1.text, 'lxml')
print(soup11)
```